# Dropping duplicate MySQL rows based on column data

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `sg` with the following columns:
`player_uuid`, `player_name`, `coins`, `kills`, `deaths`, and `wins`

However, I ran into an issue that caused some duplicate rows and some of those rows been modified. So, I am wondering how to drop the rows with older data. That said...

How do I drop the duplicate rows where `player_uuid` is the same? But I only want to drop the rows where `coins`, `kills`, `deaths`, or `wins` is smaller than it's duplicate.

Example data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xieod.png
In this case, I want to keep the row with 46 deaths and delete the row with 43 deaths.

Comment: How do you define older data? Just less kills? What if wins is different (etc)?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen An older row would be if coins, kills, deaths, or wins is less than the other row.

Comment: equal does not occur for certain?

Answer (score 0):

Failing to come up with a single delete statement due to the way the data is structured: 3 Delete statements instead:

The way it works is: Find if there are multiple rows for a given UUID, and determined which row is to be kept (Max value of the given column), then join back on itself and determine which rows are not to be kept, store in temporary table and delete all that is marked in that temporary table from the main data table (called someTable). The benefit of this approach is: If you have more then 1 duplicate (3,4,5 rows till infinity), they will also be deleted.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable AS
SELECT a.player_uuid, a.kills, b.keepRow
FROM someTable a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(kills) AS kills, player_uuid, 1 AS keepRow
  FROM sometable
  GROUP BY player_uuid
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) b ON a.player_uuid=b.player_uuid AND a.kills=b.kills
WHERE b.keepRow!=1;

DELETE a.* FROM someTable a, tempTable b 
  WHERE a.player_uuid=b.player_uuid AND a.kills=b.kills;
```

Repeat for the other columns (`wins`,`coins`,`deaths`) by replacing all `kills` with the other column names.

**Always test delete code first :)**

Also: While you are at it:

At a unique index to prevent this from happening again:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_st_nn_1 ON someTable(player_uuid);
```

When you then try to insert a faulty record, your code will just get an error in return. The best code to handle inserts in that case would be:

```
INSERT INTO someTable(player_uuid,kills) VALUES ('someplayer',1000) 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE kills=1000;
```

What also helps is having some time indicator column: Then only one delete would have to be executed:

```
ALTER TABLE someTable ADD COLUMN (last_updated TIMESTAMP);
```

Timestamps update them selves, so no code changes required to use this.